# Scrape a URL with several tables with Rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to learn how to do some **scraping** using rvest package. I´m using this [url](https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/l/leonaka01.html) to load the information, and I am trying to get the information of the table marked as "advanced" in the URL:

[image]

When I try to load the information, all I´m able to get is the first table. I mean, when I inspect using google chrome I see that the numbers in the table are marked as class="right". So this is what I tried:

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

url = url("https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/l/leonaka01.html")

read = html_nodes(read_html(url),
                         '.right')

read2 = str_replace_all(html_text(read), 
                     "[\r\n\t]" , "")
```

What I see is that read is a list of 351 values. Ok, that is he detected 351 values marked as right. If I get the last one, read2[351], I see "29.3" which is the last value of the first table.

So... how can I get the information about the other tables? I have never told R to get the first table, I supposed that I´d get all the information of all the tables and my next step would be to filter the "Advanced" table values somehow.

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Advanced" table is hidden under comments, hence it isn't directly accessible. We can get all the comments together using `xpath` and then parse the table from it.

```
library(rvest)
url = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/l/leonaka01.html"

url %>%
  read_html %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = '//comment()') %>%
  html_text() %>%
  toString() %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_node('table#advanced') %>%
  html_table() 

#      Season Age  Tm  Lg Pos   G    MP  PER   TS%  3PAr   FTr ORB% ...
#1    2011-12  20 SAS NBA  SF  64  1534 16.6 0.573 0.270 0.218  7.9 ...
#2    2012-13  21 SAS NBA  SF  58  1810 16.4 0.592 0.331 0.240  4.3 ...
#3    2013-14  22 SAS NBA  SF  66  1923 19.4 0.602 0.282 0.195  4.6 ...
#4    2014-15  23 SAS NBA  SF  64  2033 22.0 0.567 0.234 0.307  4.8 ...
#5    2015-16  24 SAS NBA  SF  72  2380 26.0 0.616 0.267 0.306  4.7 ...
#6    2016-17  25 SAS NBA  SF  74  2474 27.6 0.610 0.295 0.406  3.7 ...
#7    2017-18  26 SAS NBA  SF   9   210 26.0 0.572 0.315 0.342  3.1 ...
#8    2018-19  27 TOR NBA  SF  60  2040 25.8 0.606 0.267 0.377  4.2 ...
#9    2019-20  28 LAC NBA  SF   6   183 35.1 0.572 0.230 0.319  5.5 ...
#10    Career  NA     NBA     473 14587 22.8 0.599 0.276 0.318  4.8 ...
#11            NA              NA    NA   NA    NA    NA    NA   NA ...
#12 7 seasons  NA SAS NBA     407 12364 22.1 0.597 0.279 0.305  4.8 ...
#13  1 season  NA TOR NBA      60  2040 25.8 0.606 0.267 0.377  4.2 ...
#14  1 season  NA LAC NBA       6   183 35.1 0.572 0.230 0.319  5.5 ...
```

Comment: Ok, understood. So every table that is after some comments is hidden?

Comment: Yes, there are lot of tables in the comments on that page. You need to find the id of the table and use it in the second `html_nodes` in place of `#advanced` to get any other table.