# R Studio: subscript out of bounds when scraping tables

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

Attempting to scrape the 5th table (Team Per Game Stats) from https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2020.html and getting error "Error in teamStats[[1]] : subscript out of bounds". Any help will be great!

```
library(rvest)
get_teamStats <- function(){
  url <- paste0("https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2020.html")
  print(paste(url))
  teamStats <- url %>%
    xml2::read_html() %>%
    html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="team-stats-per_game"]') %>%
    html_table()
    teamStats <- teamStats[[1]]

  head(teamStats)
  return(teamStats)
}
```

Comment: Which table do you want? Is it "Conference Standings" or "Team Per Game Stats" ?

Comment: Team Per Game Stats

Comment: I think the table is under comments. Use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58725125/scrape-a-url-with-several-tables-with-rvest/ change last line to the id of the table `html_node('table#team-stats-base')`

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you